# XSD schema target namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema, gml, ogc

I'm trying to set up a new gml Feature schema however I think I'm misunderstanding something with the namespace. Heres my schema:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/dar" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://localhost/dar">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd" />
<xs:element name="Region" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="regionId" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="regionName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element ref="gml:Polygon" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And heres my test xml doc:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://localhost/dar" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/dar http://localhost/dar/DariusFeatures.xsd
http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#63266405">
        <gml:lowerCorner>10 10</gml:lowerCorner>
        <gml:upperCorner>20 20</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
    <Region>
        <regionId>region432762</regionId>
        <regionName>Southern Block</regionName>
        <gml:Polygon>
            <gml:exterior>
                <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:coordinates>38.324,21.754 38.424,21.754 38.424,21.854 38.324,21.854 38.324,21.754 </gml:coordinates>
                </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:exterior>
        </gml:Polygon>
    </Region>
</gml:featureMember>
```

Now the schema validates fine in eclipse however when I try to validate the xml doc, eclipse tells me that the schema file's target Namespace is "null" ?

As can be seen I've deployed the schema on `localhost`.
Can anyone see where I've messed up?

Comment: Why do you have xmlns="http://localhost/dar" in your schema root?

Comment: Thanks, your right thats not needed, however it wasn't the issue, I've removed it and I'm still getting the same validation errors

Comment: Your example is invalid, you are missing a closing `</wfs:FeatureCollection>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following line to your xml schema:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" />
```

Given that line (and elementFormDefault="qualified" in xs:schema, as Ian said), xml should validate.

Comment: Sorry, didn't help, also I don't see how it could help since _Feature element is under the gml namespace, wfs just makes use of it

Answer (score 0):

Short version: you need to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to your `xs:schema` element.

Longer version: by default only the top-level element declarations in a schema go into the target namespace, elements nested inside complex types are not declared into a namespace. Therefore the schema as written currently expects `regionName` and `regionId` to be in no namespace, but your XML document has them in the `http://localhost/dar` namespace. The `elementFormDefault` causes the nested "local" elements to take on the target namespace as well.

Comment: That makes sense however I added elementFormDefault="qualified" to http://localhost/dar/DariusFeatures.xsd, refreshed eclipse, and I still get the same validation error that target namespace is null, any other suggestions?

Comment: @user143278 I notice you don't have the `http://www.opengis.net/gml` namespace listed in `xsi:schemaLocation`, maybe that's what it's complaining about.

Comment: thats not needed since http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd imports it internally

Answer (score 0):

Well, Its been several days and the validation problem still remains a mystery.
As a work around, I've discovered that theres a newer version of OGC's Web feature Service at:
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd
which uses gml 3.2 instead of gml 3.1.1

After small changes to use this new format everythings fine!